# How to receive results from an HTML form on same page

Tags: php, html, forms

I am writing a project for one of my classes, essentially a few HTML webpages all working from a local folder. One of the pages is a form, and the project requires us to display the results of the form next to their respective fields. However, I am not sure how to do this. Here is roughly what the code looks like (sorry for my bad indentation).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Reservation Form</title>
                    <b>
                <a href=index.html>Home</a>
                <a href=yurts.html>Yurts</a>
                <a href=#>Activities</a>
                <a href=reservations.html>Reservations</a>
            </b>
            <style type="text/css">
                    div{
                            height: 705px;
                            width: 500px;
                            border: 2px solid red;
                            margin: 200px;
                            padding: 10px;
                    }
                    a:link{
                        padding-right 10px;
                        font-size: 18px;
                        color: 2309CA;
                    }
                    a:active{
                        color: #66027C
                    }
            </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>

                <h2>Reservations</h2>
                    <p style="font size: 20px;"><b>Contact Us Today!</b></p>
                <h2>Reservations Form</h2>

        <form>
        <table>
        <tr>
        <td>
  <label for="First-name">First Name:</label></td>
  <td><input type="text" id="First-name" name="First-name"required ></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
        <td>
  <label for="lname">Last Name:</label></td>
  <td><input type="text" id="lname" name="lname"required ></td>
  </tr>
  <tr rowspan="2">
  <td><b>Address</b></td>
  </tr>
   <tr>
  <td><label>Number & Street:</label></td>
  <td><input type="text" name="Name and Street" required></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td><label >City:</label></td>
  <td><input type="text"  name="city" required></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><label >State:</label></td>
  <td><name="state" required>
<select>
    <option value="Placeholder">Please Select</option>
    <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
    <option value="AK">Alaska</option>
    <option value="AZ">Arizona</option>
    <option value="AR">Arkansas</option>
    <option value="CA">California</option>
    <option value="CO">Colorado</option>
    <option value="CT">Connecticut</option>
    <option value="DE">Delaware</option>
    <option value="DC">District Of Columbia</option>
    <option value="FL">Florida</option>
    <option value="GA">Georgia</option>
    <option value="HI">Hawaii</option>
    <option value="ID">Idaho</option>
    <option value="IL">Illinois</option>
    <option value="IN">Indiana</option>
    <option value="IA">Iowa</option>
    <option value="KS">Kansas</option>
    <option value="KY">Kentucky</option>
    <option value="LA">Louisiana</option>
    <option value="ME">Maine</option>
    <option value="MD">Maryland</option>
    <option value="MA">Massachusetts</option>
    <option value="MI">Michigan</option>
    <option value="MN">Minnesota</option>
    <option value="MS">Mississippi</option>
    <option value="MO">Missouri</option>
    <option value="MT">Montana</option>
    <option value="NE">Nebraska</option>
    <option value="NV">Nevada</option>
    <option value="NH">New Hampshire</option>
    <option value="NJ">New Jersey</option>
    <option value="NM">New Mexico</option>
    <option value="NY">New York</option>
    <option value="NC">North Carolina</option>
    <option value="ND">North Dakota</option>
    <option value="OH">Ohio</option>
    <option value="OK">Oklahoma</option>
    <option value="OR">Oregon</option>
    <option value="PA">Pennsylvania</option>
    <option value="RI">Rhode Island</option>
    <option value="SC">South Carolina</option>
    <option value="SD">South Dakota</option>
    <option value="TN">Tennessee</option>
    <option value="TX">Texas</option>
    <option value="UT">Utah</option>
    <option value="VT">Vermont</option>
    <option value="VA">Virginia</option>
    <option value="WA">Washington</option>
    <option value="WV">West Virginia</option>
    <option value="WI">Wisconsin</option>
    <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
</select>               
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td><label >Zip Code:</label></td>
  <td><input type="Number"  name="city" required></td>

 </tr>
 <tr>
   <td><label >Check-in Date:</label></td>
  <td><input type="date"  name="Check-in" required></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><label >Check-out Date:</label></td>
  <td><input type="date"  name="Check-out" required></td>
  </tr>
   <tr>
    <td><label >Number of People:</label></td>
  <td><input type="Number"  name="Number of People" required></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td> <label >Phone:</label></td>
  <td><input type="text"  name="phone" placeholder="(###)###-####" required>
  <span class="ExampleNumber">(###)###-####</span>
  </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><label >E-mail Address:</label></td>
  <td><input type="Email"  name="email" placeholder="name@domain.com" required></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td> <label >Payment Method:</label></td>
  <td><name="payment" required>
<select>
    <option value="Placeholder">Please Select</option>
    <option value="MC">MasterCard</option>
    <option value="VISA">Visa</option>
    <option value="AMEX">American Express</option>
    <option value="DS">Discover</option>
</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><label >Card Number:</label></td>
  <td><input type="Number"  name="cc" required></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><label ><b>Special Request:</b></label></td>
  <td ><textarea style="width:130%;height: 300%">Enter your request here</textarea> </td>
  </tr>
  </table>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
  <button>Clear</button>
</form>
<p>
Resort<br/>Street Address<br/>State ZIP<br/>Phone<br/><br/>
                <em>Copyright &copy; 2020 Resort<br/>
                <a>example@domain.com</a></em>
</p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Essentially I would like the results to be displayed in a similar fashion to how they were inputted, on the same page after submitting. I am not too good with PHP or CSS either, if so I probably would've had this figured out. Any help at all would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! As far as the JavaScript, what have you tried? Several things to consider: 1) use jQuery. It will made referencing the form and list objects easier. 2) Use the onclick event to gather the form data and populate the list with that data. 3) If you also need to save the data at the server, use Ajax. If you want an answer that works, show some effort at the Javascript code.

Comment: You need to start learning a back-end programming language like node.js, python, php. Also what the above comment already suggested you.

Answer (score 0):

In your form you have to put the action attribute pointing to the same file.

Then in your same file you can print the value of your inputs using the PHP super global $_POST according to the name of your inputs like this:

```html
<form action ="yourFile.php" method="POST"> 
  <!--All your html here-->
 <input type="text" name="yourFirstInput"> <?php echo isset($_POST['yourFirstInput']) ? $_POST['yourFirstInput'] : ''; ?>
</form>
```

Comment: Hmm, so do I now need to save this code as a PHP instead of HTML?

Comment: @Teej yes bascially just change the file extension, all the HTML code can live inside the .php file and you can use PHP tags

Comment: Okay, I'm gonna go try this out now. One last question, I need to append this PHP to the end of every input, correct?

Comment: @Teej In order to have it next to the HTML input yes. Be aware that you can do big php blocks inside the php tag